# compare mount and /etc/filesystems in AIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

I want to compare the output put of mount command to the /etc/filesystems. Basically we want to validate everything is getting mounted properly as defined in /etc/filesystems after any system change(reboot etc.)

My basic script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mountpoint="/vol/test/abc"

if grep -qs "$mountpoint" /etc/filesystems; then
  echo "good"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```

Is this right approach? Please suggest. Also How can I get all the volumes that are being returned by executing mount command?

Answer (score 1):

I think the general approach you want is to first generate a list of all the filesystems that you *expect* to be mounted, by looking at /etc/filesystems (use some combination of awk, grep, etc. to get just the names).

Then, get the list of filesystems that are *actually* mounted by running the *mount* command with no arguments.

Finally, compare the original list with the second list, and make sure nothing is missing.

Answer (score 1):

As z242 suggested:

```
# Matching lines from /etc/filesystems
sed -n 's%^\(/.*\):%\1%p' /etc/filesystems | sort -o f1
# Matching lines from mount command
mount | tail +3 | awk '{print $2}' | sort -o f2
# Now compare the two
comm -3 f1 f2
```

Items listed with no indent are those in /etc/filesystems but not mounted.  Items listed with an indent are those mounted but not in /etc/filesystems.  If you don't care about the latter change `comm -3` to `comm -23`